# How to connect these 2 statements in python

Tags: python

```
if ask == "yes" or ask == "Yes":
    print("lets go, if you dont know a question you can say 'I dont know' to leave the gameshow")
else:
    if ask == "no" or ask == "No":
     print("then go home")

    exit(ask)

print("What is the capital of Sarajevo?")

if ask == "sarajevo" or ask == "Sarajevo":
  print("Correct, you get to move on")
else:
    if ask == "i don't know" or ask == "I don't know":
     print("Sorry that isn't correct, you lost")
     exit(ask)
```

whatever i try they all just end up being printed

Comment: Where are you initializing `ask`, please put a working code or at least something that I can copy and run on my system. The code you put cannot be run.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What does "connect these 2 statements" mean?

Comment: I want to connect the 2 if statements and possibly add more in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For the whole thing to make sense, `ask` has to be provided by the user using `input()`. So i am going to assume it is. Below is a modified version of your code. Note that you do not have to get the case correctly. You can simply convert whatever answer you were given to lowercase using the `lower()` method of strings.

```
ask = input('Please provide an answer..\t')
if ask.lower() == "yes":
    print("lets go, if you dont know a question you can say 'I dont know'")
    print("What is the capital of Sarajevo?")    
    ask = input('Please provide an answer..\t')
    if ask.lower() == "sarajevo":
        print("Correct, you get to move on")
    else:
        print("Sorry that isn't correct, you lost and have to leave the gameshow")
elif ask.lower() == "no":
    print("then go home")
```

Take a look at it and tell me if this works for you. ☺

Comment: This works but is there a way i can add more code below it?

Comment: of course you can but if you want to have more rounds of QA you can't nest `if-else` loops for ever. You would need some other kind of structure like a `while` statement with a dictionary of questions as keys and answers as values..

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand which 2 statement you want to connect 
Check this if this works for you :

```
if ask == "yes" or ask == "Yes":
    statement 1 = "lets go, if you dont know a question you can say 'I dont know' to leave the gameshow"
    print("lets go, if you dont know a question you can say 'I dont know' to leave the gameshow")
elif ask == "no" or ask == "No":
    print("then go home")
    statement 2 = "then go home"
exit(ask)

print("What is the capital of Sarajevo?")

if ask == "sarajevo" or ask == "Sarajevo":
     print("Correct, you get to move on")
     statement 3 = "Correct, you get to move on"
elif ask == "i don't know" or ask == "I don't know":
     print("Sorry that isn't correct, you lost")
     statement 4 = "Sorry that isn't correct, you lost"
 exit(ask)

statement = statement 1 + statement 3 
print statement
statement = statement 2 + statement 4
print statement
```